# Ajustar elementos al colapsar barra lateral

Tags: html, jquery, css

Tengo la siguiente pagina que me muestra datos asi cuando el menu lateral esta colapsado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando el menu esta en su posicion origial los elementos se corren hacia un lado y se pierde hacia la derecha

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que debo agregar para que los elementos se adapten cuando la vista este colapsada y cuando no? (Pienso que es la hojas de estilo o usando de jQuery)

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Hola, puedes mostrar un mínimo de código para saber si estás haciendo algo mal? Estás trabajando con tu propio CSS o es con un framework tipo bootstrap o una plantilla?

Comment: @EdgarGutiérrez plantilla `AdminLTE`

Comment: Te recomiendo leer como crear un [mcve]

Comment: @Baker falta tu código en la pregunta, como ya te comentaron (creo que tenés la suficiente experiencia en el sitio como para saberlo). Además, veo que es una plantilla de Bootstrap. Agradecería que se mencione esto en la pregunta, sin tener que buscar a qué te estás refiriendo... Estoy votando para cerrar, al menos hasta que se edite con la información que falta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al hacer uso de `AdminLTE` lo que necesitas es utilizar un `div` con la clase `box` como el siguiente código:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="box-header with-border">
        <h3 class="box-title">Title</h3>
        <div class="box-tools pull-right">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Collapse">
            <i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Remove">
            <i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
        </div>
   </div>
   <div class="box-body">
       Start creating your amazing application!
   </div>
       <!-- /.box-body -->
   <div class="box-footer">
       Footer
   </div>
        <!-- /.box-footer-->
</div>
```

Se compone de un `header`, `body` y `footer` los cuales te dejaran algo como lo siguiente:

[image: AdminLTE]

Un contenedor en el cual vas a distribuir las 12 columnas y al momento de abrir y cerrar tu menú lateral el contenido no se te deformara como te sucede ahora.